# Problems with UINavigationController nested within moreViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, parentviewcontroller

I have UITabbarMoreController which contains a few UINavigationControllers. These UINavigationControllers then contain my custom view controllers.

So the hierarchy looks something like this:

```
UITabbarController
 - UINavigationController
  -> my custom UIViewController
 - ...(other children of UITabbarController look the same)
```

From within my custom view controller I call `[self parentViewController]` which should return a UINavigationController. And this really happens, I really do get a UINavigationController, BUT only when the particular UINavigationController is NOT inside moreNavigationController.

Since I have many children controllers in the tabbar controller, the tabbar controller creates a moreNavigationController. If I open a viewcontroller that is under moreNavigationController and call `[self parentViewController]` it returns a mysterious object with class UIMoreNavigationController

I really need to get the UINavigationController that is parent of my view controller, not the UIMoreNavigationController. Also, I tried using `[self navigationController]` with the same result. How can I get reference to the real closest parent of my viewcontroller? Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Look at this answer it has similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/9567134/277021

Comment: I've seen it, but it doesn't solve my problem. I don't need access to the moreNavigationController. I need to access my own UINavigationController, that is nested in the moreNavigationController. Thanks for trying to help though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, you can't.

Apple always try to optimise their code. One of their optimisation here is to check whether the `ViewController` displayed in the list of its `UIMoreNavigationController` is of type `UINavigationController`. Because `UIMoreNavigationController` itself is a UINavigationController it does not want to create another `UINavigationController`. It's trying to avoid `UINavigationController` nesting.

When you look at the header file of [UIMoreNavigationController](https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/UIKit/UIMoreNavigationController.h) you will notice it has a variable
`UINavigationController* _originalNavigationController;` which is accualy the original `UINavigationController` that you created and that you want to access. Unfortunetly you cant since `UIMoreNavigationController` is private.

Workaround (ugly)

Pass the reference of your NavigationController to its children when you push them on it's stack.

Comment: ok thanks, that explains why the other approach I tried -> using `tabbarcontroller.selectedViewController` didn't work either the way I expected it